# how to create multilingual static block

Tags: cms, localisation, store-view, blocks

I need to create multilingual static block. So far I have created static block with id 'delivery_returns'.

I'm calling it in catalog\product\view.phtml like this:

```
$deliveryBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('delivery_returns');
echo $deliveryBlock->getTitle();
echo $deliveryBlock->getContent();
```

I understand that to translate this block:

1. I should just create another one.
2. Choose my desired language from store_view field
3. and keep the static block identifier same as original.

This method works with 'footer_links' and also with another static block I made, called 'header_links', but apparently it is not working with 'delivery_returns' block.
Changing store language does not load corresponding translated 'delivery_returns' block

What am I missing?
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Create a static block for each language, all with the same
   identifier.
2. Render the block with the `cms/block` block. It will
   automatically add the store ID to load the correct version of the
   block.

Here's an easy way to load and render the block directly in the template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('delivery_returns')->toHtml() ?>
```

Alternatively, declare the block in a layout file and render it with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('delivery_returns') ?>`:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="product.delivery_returns" as="delivery_returns">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>delivery_returns</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Comment: I did not know this. Awesome.

Comment: Mind this gives some issues regarding block caching. Not sure how to fix yet besides turning off the magento cache for this specific block... :(

Comment: More info regarding magento chache issues with blocks with multiple store views see http://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/Static-blocks-are-mixed-between-store-views-after-upgrading-to-v/m-p/10399#M655

Answer (score 8):

The answer below talks about setting the store id prior to loading the model, but, as @benmarks noted in the comment below, this is unnecessary, as that happens in the block's _toHtml().

As with many other mage models, try setting the desired store id *before* loading the model:

```
$deliveryBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
                     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                     ->load('delivery_returns');

echo $deliveryBlock->getTitle();

/**
 * You shouldn't print the content directly (although I'm assuming it's for debugging purposes only).
 * Use the code below, so as the possible content directives (the "{{ }}" thingies) would be interpreted.
 * Check out Mage_Cms_Block_Block::_toHtml().
 */
echo Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()
                        ->filter($deliveryBlock->getContent());
```

Comment: Not necessary - the `cms/block` does this during rendering; see [`Mage_Cms_Block_Block::_toHtml()` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php#L48)

Comment: You're right. Odd, I haven't noticed. I even point the OP to that very method you're talking about.

Comment: Actually, when getting *the block*, Mage sets the store id. Whereas I directly instantiated *the model*, and that didn't have the store id set. See `Mage_Cms_Block_Block::_toHtml()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I don't see anything in [`Mage_Core_Model_Block`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Block.php) which sets the store id.

Comment: That's not the block I'm talking about, but [Mage_Cms_Block_Block](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php#L48).

Comment: I think I'm just restating what you said in the first comment. Just to be clear: there's the *model* instantiation and then there's the *block* instantiation. The latter does the store setting automatically. I assumed he wanted the former, as I saw `getModel`. But, yes, the block's the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I've accomplished this in one of a few ways:

1. Just use a different static block name, copy and translate, and refer to it in your theme separately.
2. You can use `{{translate text="text to translate"}} in any cms, static block page by implementing the following workaround:

   - copy **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php** to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php and modify the following:

--

```
public function translateDirective($construction)
{
    $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
    $text = $params['text'];
    return Mage::helper('page')->__($text);
}
```

More information/source:

http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento_how_add_translation_ability_into_cms_page_or_static_block.html

Comment: Yes, I saw those solutions. But both are workarounds. With method one I then have to duplicate product\view.phtml for every storeview. Method 2 needs .csv file edit. So both are NOT suitable for non-developer client to work with.
Isn't there proper way to do this?
With my method, client can create and change static block content and it works with header_links and footer_links. I do not understand why not work with delivery_returns :S

Comment: I wish that there were an 'easier' way - the only other  way to handle it would be to pull in the content via ajax and load it from an external source.

Comment: FWIW - I have had great luck with solution 2; I use both on a regular basis.

Comment: I thought about ajax, but this makes it even more difficult for client to change content. I guess I'll choose your method 1. and create different view.phtml files for every language.
If no soon one comes up with better solution, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Tnx anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can download a module i created based on this answer from here: https://github.com/miguelbalparda/MB_Translate/
It makes available the inline translator of Magento in CMS/Block pages.

Comment: Single link answers are not the best. Please explain what you extension does. I know what it does and I recommend it but make it a little clear for everyone.

Comment: Sure, it makes available the inline translator of Magento in CMS/Block pages.

Comment: Add it yo your answer.

Comment: I forked this repository and add translation in Category Description. Also, now you can install this module through composer, the files mapping are configured. Here you can check the module https://github.com/popovserhii/MB_Translate