# Translate Static block content

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, static-block

I have a multilingual site and for display language-specific block i have to create a different static block for each language-specific store.

Is there any methods or way available to translate static block content.

I am displaying a static block from cms pages.

I have check this thread [how to create multilingual static block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/617/how-to-create-multilingual-static-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I usually do it.
Create a block with this content:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom/template/path.phtml"}}
```

Then I create the template `customer/template/path.phtml` and inside it I'm able to use: `$this->__('Text')` or `Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Text')`.

If you don't like this approach, You can override `Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter` (that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter`) and add your translate directive similar to `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::blockDirective()` or `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::skinDIrective()`.