# Does Magento have a fallback for default email templates?

Tags: email-templates, theme-fallback

Hi I have created a module with a custom transactional email, which works fine when I place the default template file in

```
app/locale/de_DE/template/email/sales/mymail.html
```

but I need to place it into my template

```
app/design/frontend/ultimo/custom/locale/de_DE/templete/email/sales/mymail.html
```

but on this path it isn't found, I even tried other places like

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/locale/de_DE/templete/email/sales/mymail.html
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/de_DE/templete/email/sales/mymail.html
```

but neither works. Isn't there any fallback mechanism for these file? If yes, can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no fallback mechanism for the e-mail templates.
I mean there is one, but not the way you want it.
The e-mail templates are searched in `app/locale/{lang_ISO}/template/email/`.
If the template is not found then it searches in the `app/locale/en_US/template/email/`.
That's the whole fallback mechanism.

But if you need some templates that depend on the theme, then you can do it like the sales e-mails do it.
Include this in the e-mail template located in `app/locale/de_DE/template/email/sales/mymail.html`.

```
{{layout handle="my_email_layout_handle"}}
```

You can even pass some variables to it like this

```
{{layout handle="my_email_layout_handle" var1=$var1 var2=$var2}}
```

where `$var1` and `$var2` are variables you pass to the email template itself.

Now in one of your layout files create the layout handle you used above.

```
<my_email_layout_handle>
    <block type="core/template" template="my_email/template.phtml" />
</my_email_layout_handle>
```

Then create the template file `my_email/template.phtml` in your theme (or themes) where you can fill in your content.

[Read this for more details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5762/146)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you forgive me the self-promotion, but I accidently bumped into this question and would like to add that our free open source extension Yireo EmailOverride allows you to add email templates to the theme, including fallback support: https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_EmailOverride